# Count distinct value with multiple criteria (one is in a comma separated list) in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image]

I have the data as outlined in the picture above, where in column A it's "Yes/No", column B it's the name of the company, column C is their city and column D is a comma separated list of industries they belong to.

I'm trying to count the distinct number of company names by city and individual industries if they are "Yes".

I have tried using,

```
=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF((A2:A100="Yes")*(C2:C100="Mycity")*(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("IndustryName", D2:D100))),
 MATCH(B2:B100,B2:B100,0)),ROW(B2:B100)-ROW(B2)+1),1))
```

but it's not giving me results.

Does anyone have a better way to count based on the city and searching for the text in a comma separated list?

Comment: Try: `=N(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(G$2,UNIQUE(TOCOL(IF(($F3=$C$2:$C$11)*($F$1=$A$2:$A$11),$D$2:$D$11,NA()),3)))))` also i have tried using your formula and it seems to be working for me: `=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF(($A$2:$A$100="Yes")*($C$2:$C$100=$F3)*(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(G$2, $D$2:$D$100))),
          MATCH($B$2:$B$100,$B$2:$B$100,0)),ROW($B$2:$B$100)-ROW($B$2)+1),1))`

Comment: Try: `=SUM(--(UNIQUE(FILTER($B$2:$B$11,($F3=$C$2:$C$11)*(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(G$2,$D$2:$D$11)))*($F$1=$A$2:$A$11),""))<>""))`

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following formula:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>G3</kbd>

```
=SUM(--(UNIQUE(FILTER($B$2:$B$11,($F3=$C$2:$C$11)*(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(G$2,$D$2:$D$11)))*($F$1=$A$2:$A$11),""))<>""))
```

---

Or, using one single dynamic array formula:

[image]

---

```
=MAKEARRAY(ROWS(F3:F5),COLUMNS(G2:J2),LAMBDA(x,y, 
 SUM(--(UNIQUE(FILTER(B2:B11,(INDEX(F3:F5,x)=C2:C11)*
 (ISNUMBER(SEARCH(INDEX(G2:J2,y),D2:D11)))*(F1=A2:A11),""))<>""))))
```

---